# Understanding stochastic variance

Tags: statistics, variance

Variance is defined by

$Var[X] = E[(X-E[X])^2]$

where $X$ is random variable, thus a function (and not a value, despite the name) and $E[X]$ is the expected value of the function $X$.

Here I am using $(...)$ to denote a function and $[...]$ to denote a functional (so a function of functions). I found https://www.quora.com/Why-do-most-people-write-E-X-instead-of-E-X-for-the-expected-value helpful to see the difference.

The expected value $E[...]$ is a functional, so its input is not one of the output values of $X$, but the function $X$ itself. The output $E[X]$ of is a real valued scalar.

The input of the outer $E[...]$ also needs to be function, so we expect $(X-E[X])^2 = Y$ to be a random variable (function). Let's further say $X-E[X]=Z$, which would mean that $Y = Z^2$.

1. Question: What is $Z^2$ supposed to mean? "Square every value of $Z$ and return the resulting function"? Then the output would be at least a function as well. So far, in my experience, the multiplication of two functions is the convolution of the two functions - also a function.
2. Question: The term $X-E[X]$ says "the function $X$ minus the value $E[X]$. What is a *function* minus a *scalar* supposed to be? Note that it is not the "value of X minus the real value" (not $X(\omega)-E[X]$), because then $X-E[X]$ would be real value, meaning $Y$ would be a real value and that cannot be because the outer $E[...]$ functional requires a function, not a real value as input.

Comment: I feel that you are really overthinking this... Take e.g. some $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~\omega\mapsto 4\sin(\omega)$, and say $c=\mathbb{E}[X]=2$. Clearly, $X-c$ is the function $Y$ with $Y(\omega)=4\sin(\omega)-2$ - no problem. Furthermore, clearly $Y^2$ is the function $V$ with $V(\omega)=(X(\omega)-2)^2=(4\sin(\omega)-2)^2$. In what way is one of these more or less a function than the others?

Comment: @Mau314: "Over-thinking" in math? I didn't even know that was possible ;-). I have to disagree: If $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)-c$, then $Y(\omega)=4\cdot \sin(\omega)−2$. But that does not mean that $Y=X-c$. And if $Y=X-c \Leftrightarrow Y(\omega)=X(\omega)-c$ than what does the outer $E[...]$ get? A function or a value? That does make quite a different as $E[c]=c$, while $E[X]\neq X$.

Comment: If you really want to go down that road, consider a real value as a (trivial) function: $c:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~\omega\mapsto 2$. Can you then accept that $Y=X-c$ is the real-valued function on $\Omega$ with $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)-c(\omega)=X(\omega)-2$?. Functions can be very simple, and in that case $E[X]=X$ is true, and you can still consider it as having passed a function to the functional $E$.

Comment: @Mau314: I am not sure what you mean by "In what way is one of these more or less a function than the others?" Well $X$ is function, while $X(\omega)$ is not a function, it is a function evaluated at $\omega$, which results in a real value. That is why $X(\omega)\in\mathbb{R}$, while $X\notin\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You seemed to doubt that $Y=X-c$ is a function, but it is just defined as the function with the property that $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)-2$ for each $\omega$. I meant the functions $X,Y,V$ - they are declared through perfectly well-defined real expressions in $\omega$.

Comment: @Mau314: Ok, that I get. I can "live" with the statement that $Y=X−c$, the way you defined $c$ as a function and/or add the law that a function added with a constant basically means, that any output added by two, as long as we say that $Y=X-c$ is a function and not a real value, and differentiate it from $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$. The reason I am getting back to that point is because I see a real difference in $E[X]$ and $E(X(\omega))$. (Note, that I use $(..)$ for the function and $[..]$ for the functional.)

Comment: In the first case I might get 0 for $X$ being the normal distribution, while in the second case I might get whatever - depending on what $\omega$ is, since in the second case $E(X(\omega))=X(\omega)$.

Comment: No, the bracket choice for $\mathbb{E}$ cannot depend on which function you put in. It is true that for fixed $\omega$, $X(\omega)$ is a fixed number (so it can be considered as a constant r.v.), therefore we know $E[X(\omega)]=X(\omega)$. From the perspective of $E$, a number is still a random variable, only that the "computer" $E$ has an easier job.

Comment: @Mau314: Yeah, you are right! If you like, you can write all you wrote as a answer (but try to use you later comments, your first comment was really difficult to get).

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I'm happy if you feel comfortable already!

Comment: @Mau314: Let's see how my PhD supervising professor feels about the approach of interpreting the notation ;-).